# In the Facebook iOS SDK, Does the "Automatic In-App Purchase Logging" feature verify IAP purchases before logging them?

Tags: ios, facebook, in-app-purchase, facebook-ios-sdk

Does the Facebook iOS SDK feature for "Automatic In-App Purchase Logging" validate in app purchases before logging them? Facebook's docs don't mention whether they do or not, and my facebook campaigns seem to have inflated purchase numbers in their reporting.